# Optimize BigDecimal in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In a web application I concerned, there is a blizzard of BigDecimal operations. Is there any way to optimize this in both memory footprint and cpu util?

I want to write some specific implementations like `BigDecimal2` or `BigDecimal10` for making the fields like `scale` and `precision` static. Nevertheless, I am not sure how much this can improve, or how much does it impact on the codebase.

The following screenshot is taken from jfr:

[image]

Comment: One way to improve a large amount of BigDecimal arithmetic being used is to use less BigDecimal arithmetic. What is it being used for? Are there alternatives?

Comment: @harold Most of them are used for switching amount between different currencies, calculating coupons or taxes. Yeah some of them could be replaced by double float point operations I think, although it’s quite subtle.

Comment: Could it be done with fixed-point arithmetic (implicitly scaled by a fixed power of ten) with plain old `long`?

Comment: It’s a good idea.  Let me check the codebase to see if it’s possible. Thank you very much @harold

Comment: Make sure that you have a good test suite which will pick up any problems you introduce.

Comment: And do not even consider floating-point.

Comment: Floating-point is [*not* the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) here.

Comment: The fact that your JFR screenshot shows that you're calling `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` means that your application may be experiencing loss of precision, as you're using double _somewhere_. It may be unavoidable (for example, if you're calculating options/futures/derivatives, it would be unavoidable). But if double can be avoided, avoid it.